# How to get pkg properties in machine readable format on Solaris 11

Tags: package-management, solaris

I would like to be able to extract (from within a shell script) the attributes of an IPS package. Basically I'm after exact same information as is listed with the `pkg info` command, but unfortunately this command list information in a format which is not very friendly to read from within a script. Example below:

```
$ pkg info archiver/gnu-tar
          Name: archiver/gnu-tar
       Summary: GNU version of the tar archiving utility
   Description: Tar is a program for packaging a set of files as a single
                archive in tar format.
      Category: Development/GNU
         State: Installed
     Publisher: solaris
       Version: 1.26
 Build Release: 5.11
        Branch: 0.175.0.0.0.2.537
Packaging Date: October 19, 2011 09:11:16 AM
          Size: 1.73 MB
          FMRI: pkg://solaris/archiver/gnu-tar@1.26,5.11-0.175.0.0.0.2.537:20111019T091116Z
```

I was hoping for something like `pkg get-property pkg.summary archiver/gnu-tar` to be available as a command but can't find such command. I would really hate to try to parse the above output. Secondly the man pages clearly states that the output from `pkg info` is intended to be read by humans, not machines.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Most of what `pkg info` reports comes from the *set* actions in the package which define package attributes and other metadata.   For your example of archiver/gnu-tar:

```
% pkg contents -t set -o name,value archiver/gnu-tar
NAME                          VALUE
info.classification           org.opensolaris.category.2008:Development/GNU
info.source-url               http://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/tar/tar-1.26.tar.bz2
info.upstream-url             http://www.gnu.org/software/tar/
org.opensolaris.arc-caseid    PSARC/2000/488
org.opensolaris.consolidation userland
pkg.description               Tar is a program for packaging a set of files as a single archive in tar format.
pkg.fmri                      pkg://solaris/archiver/gnu-tar@1.26,5.11-0.175.1.0.0.20.0:20120709T173816Z
pkg.summary                   GNU version of the tar archiving utility
variant.arch                  ['i386', 'sparc']

% pkg contents -H -t set -o value -a name=pkg.summary archiver/gnu-tar
GNU version of the tar archiving utility
```

Comment: Perfect!  You variation of `pkg contents` was indeed what I was looking for. Not very logical that you would use the 'set' action when all you want is to display a value. I would NEVER have figured this out by reading the `pkg` man page.

Answer (score 2):

Here is how I would do it by parsing pkg info output:

```
$ pkg info archiver/gnu-tar | nawk '
/^ *[A-Za-z ]*:/ {
    gsub("^ *","",$1)
    if(NR>1) printf("\n")
    name=substr($0,1,index($0,":")-1);
    value=substr($0,index($0,":")+1);
    gsub(" ","_",name);
    printf("%s=%s",name,value)
    next
}
{
  gsub("^ *","",$1)
  printf("%s",$0)
} ' | sed -e 's/= /="/' -e 's/$/"/'
```

Output:

```
Name="archiver/gnu-tar"
Summary="GNU version of the tar archiving utility"
Description="Tar is a program for packaging a set of files as a singlearchive in tar format."
Category="Development/GNU"
State="Installed"
Publisher="solaris"
Version="1.26"
Build_Release="5.11"
Branch="0.175.0.0.0.2.537"
Packaging_Date="October 19, 2011 09:11:16 AM"
Size="1.73 MB"
FMRI="pkg://solaris/archiver/gnu-tar@1.26,5.11-0.175.0.0.0.2.537:20111019T091116Z"
```

Comment: Thank you so much. That is truly an amazing piece of AWK code. I wonder what would happen if the Description field would contain a colon? I'll leave the question open for some days to see if somebody can come up with a native command on how to do this. If nothing comes along I'll accept your answer. Thanks again buddy.

Comment: Nothing will happen if the description field contains a colon as only the first one is processed. By the way, I just enhanced my script to replace spaces by underscores in the field names for the script to output valid shell script assignments.